# Displaying form fields based on content of GET

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a signup form which has a select box and, dependig on which option the user chooses, certain fields are  made available. This works great with the below code which I got from another post:

```
<div id="option1" class="plan_options" style="display:none">display something</div>


$(function() {
    $('#plan').change(function(){
    $('.plan_options').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

The only problem I have is that when someone comes to the signup form from the product pages I am passing a variable via a GET which is one of the plan options which the above code applies to. The select is properly populated with the right value but the above code doesn't work and the div is not displayed. If I manually change to one of the appropriate selects (including the one passed through the GET it works fine - is there anyway to get the above code to use the value of the GET?

Comment: How/what are you passing to this page from the product page?

Comment: I am passing a value in the url - signup.php?plan=option1 for example and there is an entry in the plan select called option1

Comment: Ah, I see. jQuery core doesn't have have any appropriate function for this matter. There are plugins or you could use plain Javascript.

Comment: @imwill Thats not true, you just triiger the change on load.  check my answer below.  You can trigger any event such as 'click', 'mouseup', 'focus' or any other on() event.

Comment: @VIDesignz probably I misunderstood his question. I thought he wanted to capture the GET parameter of the url with jQuery.

Comment: @imwill Oooooohhh, yeah, I don't know if Jquery handles that...

Comment: @VIDesignz I just tried but I think it's not possible without a plugin or plain JS http://jsfiddle.net/imwill/7fDyB/show/light/?plan=123 ;)

Comment: @imwill It looks like your script is working? Am I missing something? :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19410/discussion-between-imwill-and-videsignz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has something to do with .change(), since the change doesn't actually happen through the GET value.  You need to trigger the change on page load. Assuming you already captured and applied the variable from GET.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/sdsVm/)

Something like..

```
$('document').load(function(){
    $('#plan').change();
});
```

Also, you should set up your function using the on() handler, like so

```
$(function() {

    $('body').on('change', '#plan', function(){
        $('.plan_options').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });

});
```

Ultimately this would be your final code... :)

```
$(function() {

    $('body').on('change', '#plan', function(){
        $('.plan_options').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });

    $('#plan').change();

});
```